# htaccess rule not following condition

Tags: .htaccess

i have a htaccess file with

```
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !mycookie [NC]
RewriteRule /*.(mp4|wav|mp3|MP3|WAV|MP4|omf|OMF|jpg|jpeg|gif)$ /noaccess.html [R=307,NC]
RewriteRule ^download\.php$ /noaccess.html [R,L]
DirectoryIndex root.php /clients/files_client.php
ErrorDocument 404 /clients/404.php
ErrorDocument 400 /clients/root.php
```

The second rewrite rule is always executed, independent from the condition. Any url containing download.php is redirected to noaccess.html no matter if the cookie exists or not. Why?

Comment: e.g. http://server.com/clients/download.php?dir=name/&file=image.jpeg

Comment: Your URL `http://server.com/clients/download.php?dir=name/&file=image.jpeg` won't match that pattern.

Comment: just an example, the real list is (mp4|wav|mp3|MP3|WAV|MP4|omf|OMF|jpg|jpeg|gif)

Comment: i updated it now.

Comment: ok good but you are redirecting to `/noaccess.html` with and without cookie value. What should be behavior when cookie is not set?

Comment: if cookie not exists = redirect
if cookie exists = do nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any [`RewriteCond`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) belongs to the [immediately following](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html#rewritecond) `RewriteRule`.

> One or more RewriteCond directives can be used to restrict the types of requests that will be subject to *the following RewriteRule*.

This means, if you want a condition for more than one rule, you must duplicate it for each rule, e.g.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !mycookie [NC]
RewriteRule /*.(mp4|wav|mp3|MP3|WAV|MP4|omf|OMF|jpg|jpeg|gif)$ /noaccess.html [R=307,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !mycookie [NC]
RewriteRule ^download\.php$ /noaccess.html [R,L]
```

---

If the condition should be valid for *all* rules, you may also exit the rule chain early with the opposite condition

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} mycookie [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule /*.(mp4|wav|mp3|MP3|WAV|MP4|omf|OMF|jpg|jpeg|gif)$ /noaccess.html [R=307,NC]

RewriteRule ^download\.php$ /noaccess.html [R,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your rules and conditions don't seem correct.

Have it like this:

```
DirectoryIndex root.php /clients/files_client.php
ErrorDocument 404 /clients/404.php
ErrorDocument 400 /clients/root.php
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !mycookie [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \.(?:mp[43]|wav|omf|jpe?g|gif) [NC]
RewriteRule (?:^|/)download\.php$ /noaccess.html [R=307,NC,L]
```

Make sure to test it after clearing browser cache completely.

Comment: Thank you, but it does not work. I want a redirect if i access files with http://server.com/file.mp3 or with http://server.com/download.php?dir=name/&file=image.‌​jpeg if the cookie is not set.

Comment: With your code the rewrite rule is executed no matter if cookie is set or not. Back to square one : )

Comment: i have done that of course. i still get redirected even if cookie is set.

Comment: Sorry, that makes no difference. The link actually is generated by php code.

Comment: I've tested this complete .htaccess on my Apache and it works perfectly fine and redirects only when cookie is not set.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i wish it would do the same on mine : )

Comment: You just need to closely look at how your cookie is being set. This rule requires cookie to be already set. Rest assured rule is correct and working.